# Replace sam and bam tags with a single sam-or-bam tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

The discussion in the [recent suggestion](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/make-tags-sam-and-bam-synonyms) to make [sam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sam) and [bam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bam) synonyms seems inconclusive with users falling on either side of the argument.

I propose we instead remove both tags and create [sam-or-bam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sam-or-bam), or [sam-and-bam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sam-and-bam), or something along those lines that would cover both. We can then make both [sam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sam) and [bam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bam) synonyms of [sam-or-bam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sam-or-bam) and thereby avoid the cognitive dissonance of having a question about sam be tagged as bam or vice versa while still having the benefit of a single tag for these obviously related subjects.

Thoughts?

Comment: Would a "sam-or-bam" tag automatically be proposed when a user types "sam" or "bam"?

Comment: @bli Yes. If the tag has been created, typing any part of it would show the `sam-or-bam` as an option.

Answer (score 6):

I'd prefer making [sam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sam) and [bam](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bam) synonyms over this. I wouldn't hold off on making those two synonyms just because one person (me) opposed it!

Comment: You're not alone. I also disagree as do at least three more people who upvoted your answer. As many as have upvoted the question suggesting the merge. Now, this compound tag might indeed not be the best solution either, I'm just throwing suggestions around to see what will stick, but it isn't in any way only because you disagree!  Making them synonyms just feels wrong to me; if a question is specific to a sam file, adding bam to it seems off.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed the up votes! Truth be told, I really don't have any better suggestion than your proposal, other than perhaps just forgetting the synonyms altogether.